# App stops after push view to nav controller

Tags: ios

I've a problem. First my app works fine without any problem. But the I've added a second UIPickerView to my new DetailViewController. After this step my app stops after pushing the DetailsController to my nab-Controller without any crash or error message. If I remove the addSubview-command from this new Picker my DetailsController was shown without problems.

What can be the reason?

Comment: For a UI problem like this, I think you're going to need to show some code (i.e. where you add the second `UIPickerView`... programatically or did you do that in a xib file?).  Maybe also a screenshot of the interface or xib file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my issue: I forgot to set return value to method numberOfComponents: